# Create an Apk with python script

Tags: python, android, selenium-webdriver, apk, screen-scraping

Good morning I wanted to know if it would be possible to convert or run a script in python by converting it into an Android application, the script in question performs webscraping using selenium.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

They are apps like [Pydroid 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=en_US&gl=US) that let you run python code on an android device in more of an IDE fashion.

More to your question:

They are projects out there such as [python-for-android](https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/) that do as you described, however, it always recommended to use officially supported development methods for the device you want to target. (For android: Android Studio (Java/kotlin) , Flutter (Dart) etc)